# Import data to database using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a gridview with 1000 rows and I also have an export & import functionality. For ex. when I export 100 rows and do changes to them, and import them again, then only those 100 rows changed will be reflected. The remaining changed rows remain the same.

I am using this code below to import data to the database. Now how can I add new rows while importing on top of this working model.

Really appreciate any guidance.

**CODE:**

```
protected void btnImportXL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strSqlTable = "##TempupdatePm";
    string sexcelconnectionstring = "";
    string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadExcel.FileName).ToLower();
    // string path = FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;
    string query = "";

    string FileName = string.Empty;
    //GridView2.Visible = false;
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
    string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
    string FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];
    //  string path = FileName;

    //Get file name of selected file     
    string path = Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(FileUploadExcel.FileName));
    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(FolderPath) + path);
    //Save selected file into server location         
    FileUploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FolderPath) + path);
    //Get file path     
    string filePath = Server.MapPath(FolderPath) + path;

    if (strFileType != String.Empty)
    {
        //Connection String to Excel Workbook
        if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
        {
            sexcelconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
        {
            sexcelconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please upload the correct file format')", true);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();

            System.Data.DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string sheetname = dt.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
            query = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetname + "]";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
            oledbconn.Open();
            OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(query, oledbconn);
            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
            string create1 = "Create Table " + strSqlTable + "( [CODE] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,[Name] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,[Group] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,  [Team] [varchar](10) NOT NULL, [Size1] [varchar](10) NOT NULL, [Size2] [varchar](10) NOT NULL";

            SqlConnection sqlconn2 = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            SqlCommand sqlcmd2 = new SqlCommand(create1, sqlconn2);
            sqlconn2.Open();
            sqlcmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlconn2);
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = strSqlTable;
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);



            string update1 = "update o set o.Size1=t.Size1,O.Size2=t.Size2 from  Application as o inner join ##TempupdatePm as t on(o.CODE=t.CODE )and (o.Team=t.Team) and (o.Group=t.Group) where (o.CODE=t.CODE ) and (o.Group=t.Group)";
            SqlCommand sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand(update1, sqlconn2);
            sqlcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            string drop1 = "drop Table " + strSqlTable;
            SqlCommand sqlcmd3 = new SqlCommand(drop1, sqlconn2);
            sqlcmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oledbconn.Close();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            sqlconn2.Close();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data saved successfully');window.location='ApplicationInfo.aspx';", true);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        //objDA.BindGrid(GridView1, "select * from " + strSqlTable);
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please select a file to import the data.')", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You would like to know how to import to to sql while updating?

Comment: @Jonny - yes exactly. On top of this update I may want to add new rows while importing which is currently not present in the existing table.

Comment: I see you have an idea of what you want to do, I think that before i help you out with it, try to make one sql statement to cater for all.
you need to have a if not exist statement to insert and an update if exist :) that should cater for it :)

Comment: @Jonny - Is it possible for you to assist me in the code with the scenario?

Comment: I can do that :) give me a couple minutes to write something up

Comment: Which database? SQL dialects vary widely between databases.

Comment: @TomTom - It's a SQL server DB.

Answer (score -1):

you can just write a insert statement before update something like

```
Insert in to table select CODE,Size1,Size2 from #temp_table where CODE not in (Select code from table )
```

Then proceed as before.

Comment: who ever have down voted, please explain what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: It was me. I meant to click upvote and theres a timer restricting me of upvoting. :) will change that in a bit

Comment: can you edit your anser, Just put a colon in somewhere please

Comment: insert into Application Info select Code, Name, Group, Team, Size1, Size2 from ##TempupdatePm where code not in (select code, Name, Group, Team) from Application Info //But there is a problem with the query formation. Pls advice. `Error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.`

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this with your sql query to insert and update with one query.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (field1, field2, fieldN)
VALUES ("value1","value2", "valueN")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
field1=VALUES(value1)
field2=VALUES(value2)
fieldN=VALUES(valueN)
//and so on.
```

Comment: And how do you do that given that sql server does not support this syntax?